# Can I create an array without variable assignment with a Fortran?

Tags: fortran

I want to create an NxN array whose size is the number of N values I enter.

Can you create an array that has the size of the number I enter, not the same as the existing Fortran variable declaration real*8 Matrix (100, 100)?

Comment: Yes, you can.  Get a book that describes the Fortran language.  It will tell you how to do it.

Comment: Are you aware of Fortran `allocatable` arrays? I am pretty sure it is a duplicate, but I still can't find a good one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's what allocatable arrays are for.

```
program allocate_test
    use iso_fortran_env, only: real64
    implicit none
    real(kind=real64), allocatable :: Matrix(:,:)
    integer :: N

    print *, "Enter size of square array: "
    read(*, *) N
    allocate(Matrix(N, N))
    ! Now you have an NxN Matrix.
    deallocate(Matrix)
    ! Now you can select a new size of the Matix
end program allocate_test
```

A few things:

1. `real*8` is not standard Fortran. I have presented a method that works with Fortran 2008 (or later) compliant compilers. Use the intrinsic function `selected_real_kind` for Fortran 90/95
2. You can use this to create an array of different length, but you can't change the rank (dimension) of this thing. For example in my code above, `allocate(Matrix(N, N, N))` would not work.